# Is there only Apache Axis wsdl2Java or there is any other library?

Tags: java, web-services

I have used Axis wsdl2Java, I am wondering is there any other way to create web service client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JAX-WS (the standard Java SOAP API) is included since Java 6 and provide enough functionality for most web service clients without having to add any 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I learned to work with [WS Import](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/jax-ws-ea3/docs/wsimport.html) last year. Unfortunately I've forgotten how it works, but it was pretty easy.